# Regex.Split ignores empty results

Tags: c#, regex, split, edifact

I have this string:

```
IMD+F++:::PS4 SAINTS R IV R?+GA'
```

I would like to split it up in two steps. First I would like to split on + except escaped plusses "?+". Second I want to split the result on :, except escaped colons "?:".

With the following Regex I can successfully split my string:

```
string[] Data = Regex.Split("IMD+F++:::PS4 SAINTS R IV R?+GA'", @"(?<![\?])[\+]+");
```

result:

```
[0] IMD
[1] F
[2] :::PS4 SAINTS R IV R?+GA'
```

The result is incorrect. It should be 4 inputs into the array. It removes empty resuls. I need the empty results to stay in the array. The result should be:

```
[0] IMD
[1] F
[2]
[3] :::PS4 SAINTS R IV R?+GA'
```

Does anyone know why it behaves this way? Any suggestions?

Comment: You should focus on one problem at a time - if you want to split on colons as well, I suggest you ask that as a separate question. (Given that your expected result includes colons, presumably you're not trying to do that just yet.)

Comment: Yes, I will be doing one split at a time. The main problem was keeping the empy entries in. But it's solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're explicitly saying that you want to split on "**at least** one plus" - that's what `[\+]+` means. That's why it's treating `++` as a single separator. Just split on a *single* plus - and note that you don't need to put that into a set of characters:

```
string[] data = Regex.Split("IMD+F++:::PS4 SAINTS R IV R?+GA'", @"(?<!\?)\+");
```

If you *do* want to put it into a set of characters, you don't need to escape it -the only reason for escaping it above is to say "this isn't a group quantifier, it's just a plus character". So this is equally good:

```
string[] data = Regex.Split("IMD+F++:::PS4 SAINTS R IV R?+GA'", @"(?<![?])[+]");
```

Comment: Thank you! These examples worked exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `+` after the character class. Because `+`  greedily matches the previous token one or more times. So this `[\+]+` regex matches not only the single plus but also the following pluses.

```
string[] Data = Regex.Split("IMD+F++:::PS4 SAINTS R IV R?+GA'", @"(?<![?])[+]")
```

Comment: And the character class should be changed to `[:+]`; he wants to split on colons, too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker but his expected output is different.

Comment: Hm, you're right - perhaps he was talking about what he expects after the first split. @jjtilly should clarify.

Comment: I could swear that I tried what you are suggesting. But yeah, it works. Thank you!